# Error while uploading ipa to application loader

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

[I got this error while uploading my ipa to application loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDqQf.png)

> "Please update iTMSTransporter to a newer version.(4107)"

I have the above error  while uploading my ipa to the application loader.

I'm not able to find out the path where to update this iTMSTransporter.

Could anyone help me out in solving this issue.

Comment: How you solved it?

Comment: I'm wondering this too, having the same problem. Don't understand why they closed it, he's trying to upload his binary to the app store using X-code and it's exiting in the error he stated above.

Comment: Looks very much like a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814856