# Error in Xcode 12 when trying to upload app binary to App Store Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

On Mac OS 10.15.7, in Xcode 12.1, when I try to upload my app binary to App Store Connect, I am getting:

> "App Store Connect Operation Error: Please update iTMSTransporter to a
> newer version. (4107)"

I've tried restarting my computer, deleting .itmstransporter, and various other things to no avail.

In the meantime, I've downloaded the Transporter app from the Mac App Store and have been able to submit from there by exporting the binary rather than uploading it to the App Store, but I'd like to regain the functionality in Xcode.

Does anyone have a clue on what may be causing this?

Comment: First thing I would do is try Xcode 12.2, which went final today. Also not that Apple had all sorts ot connection issues today so maybe tomorrow things will be better.

Comment: @matt Right, there was the whole thing with Big Sur. I was able to upload it through the Transporter app though. Definitely am going to install 12.2 and see if that fixes it, thanks.

Comment: @SerPounce any updates on this? was you able to upload it? i'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Blu I updated my apps using Transporter app for now. I'm going to update Xcode later on today and see if it works.

Comment: @berbie serpoune I published my app directly via visual studio & it got submitted without any issue!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally was able to solve this. Peeking around my system I found 3 versions of iTMSTransporter.
Printing the version of each using `./iTMSTransporter -version` gives the following results:

- `/Applications/Transporter.app/Contents/itms/bin/` has version 2.0.0
- `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/bin/` has version 2.1.0
- `/usr/local/itms/bin/` has version version 1.9.3

So it looks that old version in `/usr/local/itms` was used by Xcode. After deleting `/usr/local/itms` I was able to upload my binary within Xcode 12.2 and using the `xcodebuild` command line tool.

I also deleted `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter` but I do not expect that this was the real issue.

UPDATE: This also solved my issue today in Xcode 12.3 where Distribute App and xcodebuild both got stuck in a

> authenticating with the app store

Comment: i remove the /usr/local/itms/bin , and it works! thanks

Comment: Removing `/usr/local/itms` fixed it for me also. Thank you! I wonder how we got into this state.

Comment: Same as @BlackMB, I only had to remove /usr/local/itms/bin to fix the issue (that's the folder with ITMSTransporter (or whatever it's called).

Comment: I removed ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter and it worked for me too.

Answer (score 5):

I face the same issues and solved it after execute `./iTMSTransporter -updateChannel earlyAccess` on command line.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -updateChannel earlyAccess
```

or

```
/Applications/Transporter.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -updateChannel earlyAccess
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced it with XCode 13.0, the solution is just to update your XCode to the new released. Also, u can just ignore this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean build folder and try again archive.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by installing the copy of Transporter linked to in [Apple's Transporter user guide](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html), in the "Install Transporter" section.

Answer (score -1):

Application Loader isn't working anymore.

You can use Xcode or Transporter App from the App Store.
https://apps.apple.com/de/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12